# mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2

When I try to execute a command, I will encounter the following error by commandline

**mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory**

Comment: try this `php bin/magento -dmemory_limit=2G {{your comand}}`

Comment: Hello
I tried this method but it was still not helpful

Comment: That error for each and every command or for a particular command.

Comment: For each command

Comment: May I know ram? Magento need 2GB means you should have 8GB ram.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and add dmemory_limit:

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`php bin/magento -dmemory_limit=2G {{your command}}`.

`-dmemory_limit=2G` this will extend memory for command execution.

Comment: my cron is generating this error. how to fix this issue with cron.

Comment: for cron you need to increase memory limit from server.